# azure cognitive search with filters giving results when the query matches with the value start with

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have the following code where I am doing a search in my blob for json files and list the information as per query. I am doing azure cognitive search here is the sample code for the same

```
var searchClient = _searchIndexClient.GetSearchClient("customerbill");
var searchResults = await searchClient.SearchAsync<AzureSearchCustomerbillDocumentIndexer.CustomerBillIndex>(
$"Order={OrderMark}",
new SearchOptions {IncludeTotalCount = true, QueryType = SearchQueryType.Simple});
```

I will have a OrderMark something like `TEST 1234` when I pass the string as `Test 1111` it is still returning the results. So is there a way to pull only when results match exactly as per the given input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an exact match, you can wrap the search term with quotes:

```
string searchTerm = $"\"{OrderMark}\"";

SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
searchParameters.SearchMode = SearchMode.All;

var searchResults = searchClient.Documents.Search(searchTerm, searchParameters);
```

Comment: OK do I need to do document search instead of my code?

Comment: or just I need to change my search term as `string searchTerm = $"\"{OrderMark}\"";`

Comment: If I have multiple parameters then how can I update it

Comment: I performed some tests but it doesn't give result when I search for `TEST 1` `TEST 12` `TEST 123` it doesn't give me any results. Only when I give `TEST` `TEST 1234` `1234` it gives results

Comment: I see ...the problem is because the default analyzer breaks words on spaces. In your index you have the terms separated, TEST and 1 are different tokens. You need to change the analyzer to another one which one break on spaces. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers

Comment: OK any code reference for the same?

Comment: besides the link I post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers#examples

Comment: OK if I got it correctly do I need to change anything in terms of index that got created or it is from the code ?